# Finding closed form for recurrent function with 2 variables

Tags: closed-form, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to find a closed form of the following recurrent function with 2 variables:

```
if k>n,  A(n,k) = 0
```

$$
A(n,k) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}A(n-i,k-1)}{n}
$$
$$
    A(0,k) = 0
$$
$$
    A(n,1) = 1/n
$$

I've tried solving using RSolve, thought about how to do it using generating functions, or expanding it through assignment. But failed in all.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the [hyper-harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperharmonic_number)?  Though it is slightly off.

Comment: $A(n,k)$ looks suspiciously like $\frac{S(n,k)(-1)^{n+k}}{n!}$ where $S(n,k)$ is something called [Signed Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) (no idea what that is).

Comment: It does look familiar to the hyper-harmonic numbers because of the division by n, but I can't seem to find a way to extend it to 2 variables. 

Thanks for the signed Stirling number, I might try to adjust the generating function described in the paper for that.